# How to make a svg vector icons to inline css?

Tags: html, css, web, icons, inline

I honestly don't know anything about coding so I need help, I'm a graphic designer.
I recently did several icons and sent them as svg format, but they told me they needed them in "inline css"? I have no idea what that is other than maybe it has something to do with coding? can someone help me understand what is it and how do I do it?

Comment: They might be referring to Inline CSS Sprites (see CSS Tricks article, https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/ .)  This is the practice of storing multiple images into one image in a grid, then using CSS to make just the desired image/icon show up as a background image.  Have a look at the CSS tricks article.  There's no reason you couldn't achieve the same thing using your SVG icons if all the icons are similarly combined into one SVG.

Comment: Look up inline vs block CSS.